# Object-oriented C++ API for Tokyo Cabinet?

Tags: c++, database, api, tokyo-cabinet

Is there a C++ wrapper for the Tokyo Cabinet API? Obviously I can use the basic C API from C++, but I'd much rather use something that abstracted the raw functions and structures into classes.

I'm tempted to write this myself, at least for the bits of the API that I'd want to use, but it'll save time if there's one already. I checked the TC website and did some googling, but didn't turn up anything...

Answer (score 3):

[Flare](http://labs.gree.jp/Top/OpenSource/Flare-en.html) seems to provide a C++ binding to Tokyo Cabinet.  Source code on [Git Hub](http://github.com/fujimoto/flare/tree/master)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it's GPL-licensed, so using it would require me to GPL-license my code, which I won't do. (LGPL is OK.)

Comment: Well, you didn't mention that constraint in the question.  You don't have to GPL license your code if you don't distribute it.  Also, you could always ask them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Kyoto Cabinet](http://1978th.net/kyotocabinet). It's a C++ version of Tokyo Cabinet.

Answer (score 0):

Kyoto Cabinet has a more restrictive license (GPL) than Tokyo Cabinet (LGPL). Beware!